# How to convert a list of numbers into a string?

Tags: python

What I'm trying to do is take a given list:
`numlist_1: [3, 5, 4, 2, 5, 5]`
and convert it to a string using this function

```
def to_string(my_list, sep=', '):
    newstring = ''
    count = 0
    for string in my_list:
        if (length(my_list)-1) == count:
            newstring += string
        else:
            newstring += string + sep
        count += 1

return newstring
```

With the desired output to appear as:
`to_string Test
List is: 3, 5, 4, 2, 5, 5 
List is: 3 - 5 - 4 - 2 - 5 - 5`

However, I get an error which says
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'

I think this is because one of the print statements is
`print('List is:', list_function.to_string(num_list1, sep=' - '))`
and the separator is different from the one given in the function but I want to be able to accompany for both ', ' and ' - ' seperators as I have another list which uses the same function with the ', ' seperator instead.

How do I get around this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this

```
def to_string(my_list, sep=', '):
    newstring = ''
    count = 0
    for string in my_list:
        if (length(my_list)-1) == count:
            newstring += str(string)
        else:
            newstring += str(string) + sep
        count += 1

return newstring
```

However, a much concise way is this:

```
sep = ', '
sep.join(map(str,my_list))
```

Answer (score 3):

Another option:

```
sep = ', '
output_str = sep.join([str(item) for item in my_list])
```

Answer (score 0):

another way to solve this problem

```
L = [1,2,3,4,-5]
sep = ""
print(sep.join(list(map(str,L))))
```

hope this helps